# How to handle error in generateState in SyncOnSubscribe RxJava?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java, backpressure

I am trying to get the hang of creating a SyncOnSubscribe and not quite sure what to do if the `generateState` method fails during initialization of the state.

```
return Observable.create(new SyncOnSubscribe<MyState, String>() {
    @Override
    protected MyState generateState() {
        return new MyState();   // <---- what if this fails?
    }

    @Override
    protected MyState next(MyState state, Observer<? super String> observer) {
        // do something with state
    }
});
```

I can think of a couple of ways that this could be handled offhand:

1. If a runtime exception is thrown, does the library automatically
   call `o.onError`? (see EDIT).
2. I could wrap `MyState` in another variable that stores the error and I can call `o.onError` on my own the first time that `next` is invoked.

I'm just curious if there is a suggested practice around this?

Thanks!

EDIT:  I tried just throwing a runtime exception in the `generateState` method, and I think it points me to wrapping `MyState` with an error that I will inspect in the `next` method.  PLEASE comment/answer if you have a better suggestion.

```
public static Observable<String> getEventsOnSubscribe1() {
    return Observable.create((s) -> {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("getEvents3");
    });
};

/** Like 'getEventsOnSubscribe1' but wrap exception and call onError manually.  */
public static Observable<String> getEventsOnSubscribe2() {
    return Observable.create((s) -> {
        try {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("getEvents3");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            s.onError(ex);
        }
    });
};

public static Observable<String> getEventsSyncOnSubscribe() {
    return Observable.create(new SyncOnSubscribe<Channel, String>() {
        @Override
        protected Channel generateState() {
            System.out.println("SyncOnSubscribe.generateState");
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }

        @Override
        protected Channel next(Channel state, Observer<? super String> observer) {
            System.out.println("SyncOnSubscribe.next");
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onUnsubscribe(Channel state) {
            System.out.println("SyncOnSubscribe.onUnsubscribe");
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TimeoutException {
    getEventsOnSubscribe1()
    //getEventsOnSubscribe2()
    //getEventsOnSyncSubscribe()
            .toBlocking()
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    System.out.println("onCompleted");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    System.out.println("onError: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(String t) {
                    System.out.println("onNext: " + t);
                }
            });
}
```

With the `main` function above `getEventsOnSubscribe1` and `getEventsSyncOnSubscribe` both call the subscriber `onError`, but they leave the program hanging.  Using `getEventsOnSubscribe2` which wraps the exception and manually calls `s.onError`, the program is able to exit.

Comment: This appears to be an error handling bug with `SyncOnSubscribe`. I'll post a fix for it soon

Comment: @akarnokd I may have been mistaken, I can't seem to reproduce what I was seeing earlier - the program not exiting may have been due to a different library spawning a daemon thread.  I'll reply back here if I see the issue again.  Thanks!